# Contact Form 7: Is it possible to have a greyed out Submit-Button until required fields are filled out?

Tags: wordpress, button, submit, form-submit, contact-form-7

Would it be possible to have the "Submit"-button in Contact Form 7 greyed out or inactive until all requiered fields are filled out?

Where do I have to implement the code?

Thank you! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to disable submit button untill it is filled.

You can place below code in .js file or in footer.php

```
var disableSubmit = false;
jQuery('input.wpcf7-submit[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    jQuery(':input[type="submit"]').attr('value',"Sending...")
    if (disableSubmit == true) {
        return false;
    }
    disableSubmit = true;
    return true;
})

var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    jQuery(':input[type="submit"]').attr('value',"send")
    disableSubmit = false;
}, false );
```